# ag-grid is adding hard coded _1 with column definations

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Basically I have a toggle button when I click on toggle button to refresh data if grid doesn't have data and we again click on toggle button to go back it add _1 with column definition.

You can see this image If we click on toggle button to view my record if it find data in my section then it works fine

[image: image 1]

it return data fine when it found record in my section too.

[image: image 2]

In other case it does not find data in my section and we click on toggle button to move back to all records then it ad _1 with column definition

[image: image 3]

Comment: can you share the code which gets triggered when you hit the toggle button. i am suspecting that ag grid is have two column with id DpJobId and thus appending _1 to the duplicate one. refer this documentation from https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#column-ids

Comment: please share the code. it will help us to understand the problem !

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by setting colId and field property in your column definitions. If only field is used then ag-grid tries to create colId from field and it hard codes _1